# How to pass Entity Type names into generic helper, as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

I want to code a generic helper that takes an entity type name and uses it in its LINQ code.

```
public Boolean Eval( )
{
    var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<Order>().FirstOrDefault;
}
```

How do I pass in `Order` as the type name to make this code more generic? I believe it is do with `<T>`

Comment: With `<T>` you'll have a *generic*, where `T` is an actual type, not just the *name* of a type. But your question is clear and you've already got a good answer below. Just wanted to point that out on a side note for you :)

Comment: Thanks pid.... Appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public Boolean Eval<T>( )
{
   var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want that T should always be of a certain base type you could extend it to the following:

```
public Boolean Eval<T>( ) where T : YourBaseType
{
   var firstOrDefault = db.Class.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Without any constraint there will be a possibility to pass any class (even the one that is not connected with yor entities and your `DbContext`) which can potentially result in an exception. In such case it might be recommended to wrap you code with some `try/catch` block.